# Check text on position in recycler

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I have method, where i click on position my recyclerView:

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.recyclerView))
        .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<CurrencySelectorItemHolder>(1, ViewActions.click()))
```

But how i can just check on position my text for example?

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if text displayed for a certain item?

Comment: yep, but in recyclerView and on specific position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change "whatever" to the text you want :

```
Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView))
      .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem(
                hasDescendant(withText("whatever")), click()));
```

UPDATE : this code for checking text by position :

```
onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.recyclerView).atPosition(3))
    .check(matches(hasDescendant(withText("whatever"))));

public static RecyclerViewMatcher withRecyclerView(final int recyclerViewId) {
    return new RecyclerViewMatcher(recyclerViewId);
}
```

[RecyclerViewMatcher.java](https://github.com/dannyroa/espresso-samples/blob/master/RecyclerView/app/src/androidTest/java/com/dannyroa/espresso_samples/recyclerview/RecyclerViewMatcher.java)

Comment: sorry but i mean ONLY check text, i don t need click on this element.

Comment: withRecyclerView - unresolved reference. I need to create this method additionality?

Comment: @Inkognito : sorry I copied code from my test class, I added the missing function.

Comment: @Inkognito Sorry again, I didn't notice that dependency, I update my code.

Comment: mb this?) https://gist.github.com/baconpat/8405a88d04bd1942eb5e430d33e4faa2